# Function containing pandas query can't find local variable only if imported

Tags: python, pandas, subset

**EDIT Before BOUNTY:**

I would like to have a function where I can write `subset(pd.dataframe,query="col %in% list_with_substrings")`

Where it returns the same dataframe where only rows contains any of the substrings in `list_with_substrings` for the `col`.

As if i had written:  `dataframe.query("col in @list_with_substring")`

And it should be possible to import that function into another script, and not have to redefine the function everytime it is used. If redefining is the only option, then it should be done inside the function itself. So that the subset call is a single line.

**Original Post:**

I have two scripts:

"dataprocessing.py"

```
import pandas as pd
def subset(df,query):
    query = query.replace("%in%", "in @")
    query = query.replace("%!in%", "not in @")     
    return pd.DataFrame(df.query(query))
```

and "test_dataprocessing.py"

```
from dataprocessing import *

df = pd.DataFrame({'countries':['US','UK','GE','Ch',"DK","SW"]})
countries_to_subset = ['UK','CH']

subset(df,query="countries %in% countries_to_subset")
```

This produces the error:

pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: local variable 'countries_to_subset' is not defined

but if I then define the function inside the same script

```
def subset(df,query):
    query = query.replace("%in%", "in @")
    query = query.replace("%!in%", "not in @")
    return pd.DataFrame(df.query(query))

subset(df,query="countries %in% countries_to_subset")

Out: 
  countries  GDP
1        UK    2
3     China    4
```

So I can't import a function that uses query and pass it a local variable?
Is there a way to import the subset function "as if" it was defined in the same script?

tested on Python 3.6 & 3.7 and pandas 0.23.0 & 0.24.2

Comment: You appear to be forcing R semantics in Pandas. But Pandas has similar methods. Instead of `%in%` use `isin()`: `df.query('countries.isin(@countries_to_subset)')` or complement `df.query('~countries.isin(@countries_to_subset)')`.

Comment: Yes, exactly, and I would want to include other things aswell like other subsets in the same query.  You're solution would work well if it was not inside a function, but if it's from an imported function (as the question relates to) it still produces the "variable undefined error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution but the only doubt is that you have extra lines in the testing file, and using an unsafe `exec`.

## `test_dataprocessing.py`:

```
import inspect
exec(inspect.getsource(__import__('dataprocessing')))

df = pd.DataFrame({'countries':['US','UK','GE','Ch',"DK","SW"]})
countries_to_subset = ['UK','CH']

subset(df,query="countries %in% countries_to_subset")
```

And no changes with `dataprocessing.py`.

It will result as expected.

Comment: Nice, that works very well. 
Although something worth noting is that the exec command can't be run through another .py script importing it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @user2673238 That's the best i can do :-) lol, thanks so!!!! much for awarding the bounty :-)

Comment: You are welcome - It does not look pretty and it's certainly not easy to remeber the command, but It's very usefull and i've been trying to make something like this for weeks.

Comment: @user2673238 I wouldn't of looked and put effort into this if it wasn't on a bounty :-)

Comment: @user2673238 That's what bounties are for

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the easiest thing to do is use `f-strings`:

## dataprocessing.py

```
import pandas as pd


def subset(df,query):
    query = query.replace("%in%", "in") # remove @
    query = query.replace("%!in%", "not in") # remove @
    return pd.DataFrame(df.query(query))
```

## test_dataprocessing.py

```
import pandas as pd
from dataprocessing import *


df = pd.DataFrame({'countries':['US','UK','GE','Ch',"DK","SW"]})
countries_to_subset = ['UK','CH']

subset(df, query=f"countries %in% {countries_to_subset}")
```

Comment: cool trick, but I would like to write the query as "countries %in% countries_to_subset" or "countries in countries_to_subset", as if the function was created in the current script

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you evaluate the query in `subset`. 
`subset` has only access to the variables in it's scope, meaning the:

- parameters passed into the function (`df` and `query`)
- local variables (`query`)
- module scope variables: (`pd` and `subset`)

Since it is evaluated there, it has no access to any of the variables mentioned in the query.

A simple way too solve this, is instead of return the result of the query, the translated query.